# PHP Login Can't login to index.php

Tags: php, authentication

Why can't I login to my index.php page its just getting stucked in my     login.php page. Please help. Thanks.

```
<?php
session_start();

$conn = new PDO('mysql:host = localhost;dbname=userdb','root','');

if (isset($_POST['login'])){
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT('userID') FROM 'tbl_account' WHERE         'username' = '$username' AND 'password' = '$password' ");
$query->execute();

$count = $query->fetchColoumn();

if ($count == 1){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

    header("location : index.php");
    exit();

}else{
    $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
}

}

?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action = "?" method = "POST">
    <input type = "text" name="username"><br> //username
    <input type = "password" name = "password"><br> //password
    <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Login"> /button
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

where could probably my mistake? on my PDO? on my prepared statement? TIA

Comment: Wrap off quotes form table and column name instead use backtick. And must read http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: I love your prepared statement.

Comment: <form action = "?" method = "POST"> what about that question mark?

Comment: @Saty Done, and still nothing. :(

Comment: @chaoss88 Should i put there what page should i be redirecting when I have a correct log in?

Comment: @Batz Remove the question mark in the quotes.

Comment: you need an `exit();` after `header(location: .....`, you also have a weak SQL and you're inserting untrusted data into it

Comment: action missing <form action = "index.php" method = "POST">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)form action missing.

2)isset($_POST['login']) wrong name checking in  if condition.

3)prepared statement have lots of issue.

try something like this

```
            <?php
            session_start();

        //db connection

       global $conn;

        $servername = "localhost";  //host name

        $username = "root"; //username

        $password = ""; //password

        $mysql_database = "userdb"; //database name

    //mysqli prepared statement 

        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

        mysqli_select_db($conn,$mysql_database) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");

                        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                        {
                                $username = $_POST['username'];
                                $password = $_POST['password'];

                                $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_account WHERE  username =? AND password =? ");
                                $stmt->bind_param('ss',$username,$password);
                                $stmt->execute();
                                $get_result= $stmt->get_result();
                                $row_count= $get_result->num_rows;

                                $stmt->close();
                                $conn->close();

                                if ($row_count>0){

                                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

                                    header("location:index.php");
                                    exit();

                                }else{
                                    $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
                                }

                        }


     ?>



            <html>
            <head>
                <title>Login</title>
            </head>

            <body>
                <form action = "login.php" method = "POST">
                <input type = "text" name="username"><br> //username
                <input type = "password" name = "password"><br> //password
                <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Login"> /button
                </form>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: I think im getting close. But the `$stmt->bind_param('ss',$username,$password);` has an error. 
Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\Webprog\Login.php on line 23 @jothi

Comment: may be your table name or column something wrong thats why this error check it . @Batz

Comment: Thanks a lot sir! This answered my question! Hope to help me and other for further problems. Keep it up!! :) @jothi

Answer (score 0):

You have wrongly used prepared statement.

You should write,

```
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT('userID') FROM REGISTRY WHERE name = ? AND password' = ?");
$query->bindParam(':name', $username);
$query->bindParam(':password', $password);
$query->execute();
$result_rows = $query->fetchColumn(); // get result
```

Check [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) for more detail.

**Suggestion**:- also add **exit;** after **header** tag to stop execution of afterward code.

Comment: Still my login.php does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

its syntax to use an `exit();` after any `header('location [...]')` calls, you're missing this in your code which could be the reason why your page does nothing.

Also, I'd really like to touch up on some security notes: what the hell is that?

PDO has pre-written functions to allow you the full dynamics of a connection with security, they are there to be used; as it stands, your SQL statement is a security risk as you're directly inserting untrusted data into a statement without stripping it of injections.

Heres an example you could use to secure this:

```
class DB extends PDO
{
    function __construct(
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=kida',
        $username = 'root',
        $password = 'root'
    ) {
        try {
            parent::__construct($dsn, $username, $password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
            parent::setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function query($statement, array $parameters = array())
    {
        $stmp = parent::Prepare($statement);
        $i = 1;
        foreach($parameters as $parameter) {
            $stmp->bindParam($i, $parameter);
            $i++;
        }
        $stmp->execute();
        return $stmp->FetchAll();
    }
}

$Con = new DB();
$username = "example";
$row = $Con->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE username = ?", [$username]);
```

Comment: already put an exit(); but still the page does nothing. Does PDO is the issue here?

Comment: What exactly is your error? Have you debugged anything? Does your form successfully post the correct data? Do you have a connection to the Database, I see no try/catch? @Batz

Comment: The exact error that i'm trying to fix is that when i'm logging in there's nothing happening and yes i have a connection on my index.php where i put my simple sign up.

Answer (score -3):

try and change this code to
      "SELECT COUNT('userID') FROM 'tbl_account' WHERE         'username' =   '$username' AND 'password' = '$password' ");

put semicolon inside the quotes and on the outside as well

```
  "SELECT userID FROM tab1_account WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password';";
```